# $sudo apt install libpcl-dev failed to install

Tags: ros-noetic

Background info: Ubuntu 20.04 on NVIDIA

```
$sudo apt install libpcl-dev requires libboost-all-dev, libflann-dev, libvtk7-dev, and libvtk7-qt
```

I tried `$sudo aptitude ...`, but also failed.

Answer (score 1):

From the output you sent, you have dependencies which must be installed. Try

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install libboost-all-dev libflann-dev libvtk7-dev libvtk7-qt-dev
```

Then later install your desired library:

```
sudo apt install libpcl-dev
```

If it does not work, try again with aptitude, but see if are there other options besides the first one, input (n) for first solution and check other ones more suitable. If you have conflict packages, consider uninstall them or upgrade:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

But take care with this CMD since will update kernel, O.S and important libraries.

Good luck

Comment: 1) Thank you Marcus 2) Both apt & aptitude has same solution of installing all the same dependent packages. The ibverbs-providers, libibverbs1 (28.0-1ubuntu1) are the base/lowest level packages to install upper branch packages to get to libboost-all-dev libflann-dev libvtk7-dev libvtk7-qt-dev. Press n to show the second solution of aptitude. It asks to downgrade the ibverbs-providers, libibverbs1, and librdmacm1 to (28.0-1ubuntu1(focal)) from 58mlnx43-158101 & perftest (down from 4.5-0.18.gfcddefe0.58101 to 4.4+0.5-1(focal)). Please let me know if this these four packages here must go together

Comment: I will try remove the ibverbs-providers and libibverbs1 & then do the first solution again.

Comment: Removed ibverbs-providers and libibverbs1 & then did the first solution again solved the problem. Thank you, Marcus.

Comment: Congratulations ! So Please consider to accept the answer as solution